# Dummy regression group comparison

Tags: regression, anova, robust

I want to do my ANCOVA as a robust regression as assumptions are hurt. I have a categorial predictor with 5 groups but I also want to check pairwaise for all groups if they differ in their effect on the dependant variable. How am I supposed to do this? Can I just do 5 regressions where I choose a different reference group for each?

Comment: I don't have time for a full answer right now but [this paper](https://ideas.repec.org/p/boc/usug21/17.html) by Verrardi and Jan may help.

Answer (score 0):

Fairly easy way to do this in R using `{marginaleffects}`

Here is a code example.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(marginaleffects)

set.seed(0)
# Simulate data
n <- 500
x <- rnorm(n)
g <- factor(sample(1:5, size=n, replace = T))
y <- model.matrix(~x + g) %*% c(0, 1, -0.5, -0.25, 0.25, 0.5) + rnorm(n)

# Fit robust linear model
fit <- MASS::rlm(y~x+g)

avg_comparisons(fit, variables = list(g = "pairwise"))
#> 
#>  Term Contrast Estimate Std. Error      z Pr(>|z|)    S   2.5 %  97.5 %
#>     g    2 - 1   -0.374      0.144 -2.596  0.00943  6.7 -0.6564 -0.0916
#>     g    3 - 1    0.107      0.145  0.737  0.46105  1.1 -0.1774  0.3913
#>     g    3 - 2    0.481      0.148  3.251  0.00115  9.8  0.1910  0.7710
#>     g    4 - 1    0.376      0.145  2.598  0.00939  6.7  0.0924  0.6605
#>     g    4 - 2    0.750      0.148  5.063  < 0.001 21.2  0.4599  1.0410
#>     g    4 - 3    0.270      0.149  1.811  0.07016  3.8 -0.0222  0.5612
#>     g    5 - 1    0.760      0.143  5.306  < 0.001 23.1  0.4792  1.0407
#>     g    5 - 2    1.134      0.146  7.747  < 0.001 46.6  0.8471  1.4209
#>     g    5 - 3    0.653      0.147  4.437  < 0.001 16.7  0.3646  0.9415
#>     g    5 - 4    0.383      0.147  2.613  0.00898  6.8  0.0958  0.6712
#> 
#> Columns: term, contrast, estimate, std.error, statistic, p.value, s.value, conf.low, conf.high 
#> Type:  response
```

<sup>Created on 2024-02-13 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

You will likely have to adjust the p value if these comparisons were not pre-specified.

Comment: I am really stuck on this and have to finish my thesis soon. Would it be possible that I mail you my data so you could have a look?

Comment: @Emil I would gladly consult for you for a nominal fee.  Else, its best we keep things out in the open